# Are these two uses of "think of" in this sentence appropriate?

Tags: grammar

When you think of the Middle Ages, you think of first castles and knights in armor. (self-made)

There are two “think of”, are they all comprehensible? The first is in the first stage of thinking, whereas the second belongs to the second. Can other words represent the two layers of meaning of “think of” more effectively and clearly?

Comment: Writing advice and proof reading on off-topic on ELU.

Comment: I don't buy that. It's certainly more interesting than punctuation, which is apparently on-topic here. And, who knows? Maybe the horse might sing.

Comment: By the way, the sentence is fine, and both _think of_'s are clearly intended to mark a parallel construction, which is what you want, since you're going from setting up an imaginary situation to predicting the results of that situation on the reader. Using generic _you_ is just right, here. The sentence is false, of course; when ***I*** think of the Middle Ages, I think of the smell first. Castles and knights in armor is minor pageantry by comparison.

Comment: @JohnLawler: have you read the example carefully? Without *first* the sentence would be unobjectionable (and uninteresting).

Comment: Oh, that's just an odd niche for _first_; normally it would follow _think_, but it certainly can be moved closer to its focus. And, as you say, it makes it more interesting.

Answer (score 1):

The original sentence is NOT correct. The minimal change required to make it correct is this:

> When you think of the Middle Ages, you **first** think of <s>first</s> castles and knights in armor.

This sentence is perfectly acceptable. If you wanted to change it up and not use *think of* twice in the same sentence, here are some alternatives:

> When you think of the Middle Ages, **the first things that come to mind are** castles and knights in armor.

or

> When you think of the Middle Ages, **your first thoughts are of** castles and knights in armor.

or

> **When it comes to** the Middle Ages, you first think of castles and knights in armor.

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: I would say *you think first of...*, but I agree the original sounds odd.

Comment: I agree, Tim, that one works, too.

Answer (score 0):

It is never a good idea to repeat oneself as it infers a narrowness of literacy. If it were me I would say something like:

'When one thinks of the Middle Ages, one's mental images are first of castles and knights in armour.'

Comment: Nah. Way too flowery; and _one_ bespeaks formal occasions and high status. And repeating the V is a normal way to emphasize comparison between clauses.

Comment: Plus, it should be "implies" not "infers".

Comment: And "If it were me" should be "If it were I."

Comment: @rhetorician You mean 'If it were I, I would ...'. Rubbish! 'Me' is the object of the clause.

Comment: I'm pretty sure "I" is a predicate nominative, and therefore needs to be in the nominative, not objective, case. Yeah, "me" sounds better, and I'd probably use it myself in conversation; in writing, however, I'd probably--stickler that I am--stick with "I."

Comment: @rhetorician Well, I'd be surprised to hear an erudite native speaker say 'If it was I, I would complain'. And I've never heard of a 'predicate nominative'. But I would defer to any grammarian who  held differently.

Comment: The ol' "predicate nominative" takes me back more years than I'd like to admit; hence my qualification "pretty sure."  By the way, it's "If it were I" not "If it was I."  Then again, I may be wrong, as I frequently have trouble with the subjunctive mode. I think it's used when, for example, one suspends disbelief and pretends (in this case) the person referred to is I, not he or she.  You know, an impossibility.  On the other hand, "If he was here, I did not see him" is simply an expression of fact, not of an impossibility and hence doesn't require the subjunctive mode.

Comment: @rhetorician It's not a form which I recognise, but you are the rhetorician. Then there is the small matter of the Atlantic Ocean which remains an impediment to uniformity, even in the internet age. Incidentally I think it should be 'the subjunctive mood'as opposed to the 'indicative mood', and not 'mode'.

Comment: @WS2:  As the songwriters (George and Ira Gershwin) said, "You say 'toe mah' toe' and I say 'toe may' toe.' Let's call the whole thing off."  Cheers!  Don

Answer (score 0):

"think of" can refer to a volitional act

> I thought of what I'd make for dinner.
>
> Think of the children.

or an unconscious one

> When I heard that song I thought of my childhood.  *(was reminded of)*
>
> TV news makes me think of all the suffering in the world. *(brings to mind)*

In the case of the latter, the act has a causal precursor.

Rewriting the OP's sentence to explicitly make the second usage of "think of" volitional

> When you think of the Middle Ages, you also consciously choose to think of castles and knights in armor.

it seems that this is not what the OP intended to express.

Rather, it seems clear that the first usage is the causal precursor of the second and that the second is not volitional.

Therefore, I would suggest that there is no confusion in the meaning of the second usage.

The first usage could be understood as either volitional or unconscious without affecting the essence of the sentence.

> When you ponder the Middle Ages, you think of castles and knights in armor.
>
> When you are reminded of the Middle Ages, you think of castles and knights in armor.

As the essence of the OP's sentence is clear, I would suggest that, although the OP may be able to word the sentence more smoothly, both uses of "think of" in the original sentence are acceptable.